# Access Databases and connecting to ArGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, ms-access, arcgis-portal

Does anyone have any experience using ARGIS Online/Portal and connecting a MS Access database to visually represent spatially referenced data.

I have a database that is regularly updated, can I create a web application/web to display this information live?

Answer (score 1):

You will need ArcGIS for server to accomplish this, and Access Databases are not supported. See [HERE](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/system-requirements/latest/windows/arcgis-server-system-requirements.htm#GUID-A186D47C-487A-4660-B12A-4BFA11810557) for the documentation of supported Databases